# ‘numeric_limits’ is not a member of ‘std’

Tags: c++, lua, xplane

I am trying to compile an application from source, [FlyWithLua](https://github.com/X-Friese/FlyWithLua), which includes the sol2 library.

I am following the instructions but when I run `cmake --build ./build` I get the following error:

```
In file included from /home/jon/src/FlyWithLua/src/FloatingWindows

/FLWIntegration.cpp:10:
/home/jon/src/FlyWithLua/src/third_party/sol2/./upstream/sol.hpp: In lambda function:
/home/jon/src/FlyWithLua/src/third_party/sol2/./upstream/sol.hpp:7194:59: 
      error: ‘numeric_limits’ is not a member of ‘std’
7194 |               std::size_t space = (std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max)();
```

There are several other errors on the same line after this, but I guess they might just go away if I can solve this one.

there are several [similar issues](https://github.com/onnx/onnx-tensorrt/issues/474) with the solution to add the following includes to the .hpp file

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <limits>
```

the `sol.hpp` file includes the following imports:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <limits.h>
```

https://sol2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/errors.html gives some hints about the why the compiler might not recognize these includes:

> **Compiler Errors / Warnings**
>
> A myriad of compiler errors can occur when something goes wrong. Here
> is some basic advice about working with these types:
>
> ```
> If there are a myriad of errors relating to std::index_sequence, type traits, 
> and other std:: members, it is likely you have not turned on your C++14 switch for
> your compiler. Visual Studio 2015 turns these on by default, but g++ and clang++ 
> do not have them as defaults and you should pass the flag --std=c++1y or
> --std=c++14, or similar for your compiler.
> ```

the src/CMakeList.txt file has the following line:

> set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

I'm only faintly familiar with C/C++ and this all seems very complicated to me, but I'm hoping that there might be an easily recognizable cause and solution to this to someone more skilled.

`cat /etc/*-release` gives

```
DISTRIB_RELEASE=21.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=impish
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 21.10"

$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 11.2.0-7ubuntu2) 11.2.0
```

Comment: I'm slightly confused.  Do you or do you not have `#include <limits>`?  That *should* solve the problem.

Comment: Can you [edit] in the output of `g++ --version`? (or the output of clang --version if you use clang)

Comment: I have #include <limits.h> but not #include <limits>

Comment: g++ (Ubuntu 11.2.0-7ubuntu2) 11.2.0

Comment: @CHsurfer `limits` and `limits.h` are two different header files. You need the former. `limits.h` is a C standard library header.

Comment: Re. `"I have #include <limits.h> but not #include <limits>"`: then please do as suggested and `#include <limits>`.  `limits.h` is the `C` language header and knows nothing about namespaces such as `std`.

Comment: I added `#include <limits>` to sol.hpp and it compiled successfully. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> ```
> /home/jon/src/FlyWithLua/src/third_party/sol2/./upstream/sol.hpp:7194:59:
>
>       error: ‘numeric_limits’ is not a member of ‘std’
> 7194 |               std::size_t space = (std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max)();
> ```

This error message implies that `src/third_party/sol2/./upstream/sol.hpp` header uses `std::numeric_limits`, but also that `std::numeric_limits` hasn't been defined. The simplest explanation for that is that the header that defines `std::numeric_limits` hasn't been included. In such case, the solution is to include the header that defines `std::numeric_limits`.

> the sol.hpp file includes the following imports:
>
> ```
> #include <stddef.h>
> #include <limits.h>
> ```

This confirms the problem. Neither of those headers define `std::numeric_limits`.

> https://sol2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/errors.html gives some hints about the why the compiler might not recognize these includes:

Those hints may apply to some other cases, but not this one. `std::numeric_limits` has been part of the C++ standard since the beginning, so language version has no effect on its existence.

---

Conclusion: According to the quoted error message, sol.hpp uses `std::numeric_limits` which is defined in the header `<limits>`, but according to you, it doesn't include that header. If this is the case, then this is a bug in the sol.hpp file. Correct solution would be to fix the sol.hpp file by including `<limits>` in that file before using `std::numeric_limits`.

Answer (score 13):

I was able to remove this error by just including `limits` and not `limits.h` in the respective file where the error is using this statement.

```
#include <limits>
```